# Copy Data from Particular sheets and save in existing sheet"Draft"

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheets 1 2 3 4 and all contains the same set of columns(There are other tabs as well in the book with different set of columns). 
I need to copy all tab data in to one sheet which is already there in the workbook named "Draft".

I have found this code and tried:

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets() 
    Dim wrk As Workbook 
'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables

    Dim sht As Worksheet 
'Object for handling worksheets in loop

    Dim trg As Worksheet 
'Master Worksheet

    Dim rng As Range 
'Range object

    Dim colCount As Integer 
'Column count in tables in the worksheets


    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 
'Working in active workbook


    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets 
        If sht.Name = "Master" Then 
            MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _ 
            "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _ 
            "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error" 
            Exit Sub 
        End If 
    Next sht 


'We don't want screen updating

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 


'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet

    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count)) 

'Rename the new worksheet

    trg.Name = "Master" 

'Get column headers from the first worksheet


'Column count first

    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1) 
    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column 

'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed

    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount) 
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value 

'Set font as bold

        .Font.Bold = True 
    End With 


'We can start loop

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets 

'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)

        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then 
            Exit For 
        End If 

'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets

        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount)) 

'Put data into the Master worksheet

        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 
    Next sht 

'Fit the columns in Master worksheet

    trg.Columns.AutoFit 


'Screen updating should be activated

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

which is working fine but creating new tab and copied data from all tabs irrespective of required tab.

which is working fine but creating new tab and copied data from all tabs irrespective of required tab.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your code adds a new sheet?

Comment: If you don't want all sheets included, you need to use If or Select Case in your loop through the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Without any testing, and if i understand correctly what you are trying to achieve (copy your Sheet 1,2,3,4 to Draft sheet), please see below the modified code (from your working code):

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets() 
    Dim wrk As Workbook 
'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables

    Dim sht As Worksheet 
'Object for handling worksheets in loop

    Dim trg As Worksheet 
'Master Worksheet

    Dim rng As Range 
'Range object

    Dim colCount As Integer 
'Column count in tables in the worksheets


    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 
'Working in active workbook


'We don't want screen updating

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 


'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet

    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets("Draft")

'Get column headers from the first worksheet


'Column count first

    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1) 
    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column 

'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed

    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount) 
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value 

'Set font as bold

        .Font.Bold = True 
    End With 


'We can start loop

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets 

'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)

        If sht.Name = "Sheet1" or sht.Name = "Sheet2" or sht.Name = "Sheet3" or sht.Name = "Sheet4" Then

'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets

            Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount)) 

'Put data into the Master worksheet

            trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 
        End If 
    Next sht 

'Fit the columns in Master worksheet

    trg.Columns.AutoFit 


'Screen updating should be activated

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```